# Checking Keys in JSON Records using Java

Tags: java, json

```
"transaction": {
    "id": 1,
    "empid": "12345",
    "details1": {
        "name": "xyz",
        "age": "30",
        "sex": "M",
        "Address": {
            "Office": "office",
            "Home": "Home"
        }
    },
    "abcDetails": "asdf",
    "mobile": 123455
},
```

I need to test if JSON record contains more then two keys(details, Address).

Then, I need to pass those key input to this line:

```
parserValue1 = parserValue.asObject().get("firstKey").asObject().get("secondKey");
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Many json parsers have a `has("key")` or `contains("key")` accessor.

Otherwise you will have to add a condition to check if get("") returns null, or turn your whole Json object into a map, where you do the same checks.